# Count how many different ways we can organize an array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, math

I declared these arrays

```
right_opt = [1 for x in range(20)]
down_opt = [0 for y in range(20)]
lst = right_opt + down_opt
```

lst is equal to - >

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

How can I count in how many ways can I organize this array in unique ways
example : (small array)
[0,0,1,1] || [0,1,0,1] || [1,0,0,1]  
but [0,0,1,1] cant show again (even if we switch the position of the first 0 with the second)

Comment: Sound like it is related to binomial coefficient https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about math.

Comment: @PetarPetrovic The binomial coefficient does not take uniqueness into account.

Comment: Its an algorithm in math , but I need a code to solve it

Comment: if you need a code to solve it you have come to wrong place. Stackoverflow is to help you with your code. Not to write code for you.

Comment: @ZedEvans But it is the math bit that you are missing

Comment: I think it's (lenght of array) ! /2  ../2 due to 0and1

Comment: @Ev. Kounis Nevertheless, binomial coefficients gives the number of 0/1 sequences

Comment: @ZedEvans there is no need for an algorithm, the answer can be given by a formula. But I see people are confused about what this formula is. I hope my answer clarifies things.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an algorithm to count the distinct ways you can order the elements in your list, a simple formula would suffice.

The number of distinct ways you can order N unique elements is N! (that's N factorial).
If the elements have duplicates (as in your case) you divide by the number of ways you can order these duplicates.

So for your example of 20 `0`'s and 20 `1`'s the answer is (40!)/(20!*20!) = 137,846,528,820
(that's 137 billion ways to order)

Comment: You should avoid answering a question that is so clearly not proper for this site.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I see your point, but given the comments, as well as the other answer (which I see is now deleted), it was not clear that a simple formula existed. I could have provided the solution in a comment, but I thought I needed to write a bit more than what a comment allows.